# Media query with position absolute and inline-block, doesn't seem to apply on Chrome

Tags: html, css

Can someone give me a clue about this weird behaviour?

1. When the browser is wide, we have a hint on the right side of a form
   field. This is Ok.
2. When we narrow the viewport the hint gets to the bottom as it
   should.
3. When we try to re-scale the viewport to be wide again, the hint text
   overlaps other elements, instead of going to it's original position
   as intended.

Chrome V.46 on Mac OS 10.

**Step 1 - The browser is wide open - Hint text is on the right side**
[image: Step 1 - The browser is wide open - Hint text is on the right side.]

**Step 2 - If we narrow the viewport, the hint moves to bottom. OK.**
[image: If we narrow the viewport, the hint moves to bottom. OK.]

**Step 3 - When we try to resize the browser window, the hint doesn't follow is position:**
[image: When we try to resize the browser window, the hint doesn't follow is position]

**Step 4 - This is how the inspector looks like when the hint ignores the input field position:**
[image: This is how the inspector looks like when the hint ignores the input field position]

**Step 5 - I then uncheck the "position absolute" on the inspector window, and it stays like this:**
[image: I then uncheck the "position absolute" on the inspector window, and it stays like this.]

**Step 6 - Finally, I check that same checkbox, and it goes to the appropriate position.**
[image: Finally, I check that same checkbox, and it goes to the appropriate position]

As anyone had a similar issue before?

I've tried to reproduce this on a Fiddle, using the same rules, not just the exact same elements for obvious reasons, but it seems to work there:
https://jsfiddle.net/5m04na1u/1/

```
<div>Lets imagine I'm a form element wrapper</div>
<p class="hint-block">I'm a hint text block</p>

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}

.hint-block {
    display: block;
    color: blue;
}

        @media screen and (min-width : 56.25em) {
            .hint-block {
                position: absolute;
                display: inline-block;
                color: red;
            }
        }
```

Again, this is a Chrome only issue. Tried on other browsers and it worked well. But 99% of the time is my fault so, and even if it's not, I still have to fix this somehow.

Any clue or suggestion?

***Update:***
Here's a live code sample:
Sorry. I had to remove the link, because the product is not yet live, and the client had is concerns expressed.

Comment: Well if fiddle works it might be some other CSS rule that overrides those rules somehow. would be a good idea to have a look at your actual code

Comment: Some other class may override your CSS , If u post full demo HTML code in jsfiddle we can look on that.

Comment: The fiddle is somehow different from your issue. Please make it show the same problem..

Comment: Updated with a life code link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is:

- Remove `position: absolute` from help block
- Add `vertical-align: middle` to help block

Work like a charm for me

Comment: Added vertical-align: top, seems to work better than middle, while side by side with the text-box. Anyway, that worked, and seems to deal with the flexibility issue. While doesn't explain the issue on Chrome. I would report the issue, but I can't really reproduce it, so, let's keep the answer here for future reference, in case someone finds the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 
`left: 400px` to `@media screen and (min-width: 56.25em) #checkoutform-email+.hint-block` solves the layout issue, but not the root of the problem.

I believe this should be considered a browser issue. Since it calculates the initial left of the absolute element considering the width of its siblings.. After re-sizing the window, a layout happens and it won't consider the siblings width again, overlapping the inner contents..

Comment: That would be my try. Instead of assuming the auto, declare specific positions numbers...

Comment: @MEM, the downside is the fact that this should be some kind of automatic thing.. Adding a specific number may be a problem when improving responsiveness.. I'm searching for a explanation of how/why this works like this..

Comment: While that address the issue, I will test the removal of the position absolute as @jQuery00 suggests. I had those for a reason, but I have to try it out and see if it stands ok.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the position absolute. Remove it and it works automatically.

Comment: Yeah, you may layout this 'hint-block' in many ways, `absolute position` is definitely not a must..
But I think the focus of the issue should be: understand how/why that overlap happens when you use `absolute position`.

Comment: Yes, understand it is fine, but this seems to be a redraw bug in chrome, so in firefox I can't reproduce it. In chrome maybe the absolute positioning saves the position in narrow view and when resize again the window to big absolute positioning saves the ficticial top property. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score -1):

What about making a div, where you can put your input? i think it should work